# Método php que verifica duas strings em uma variável

Tags: php, laravel, string, comparação

Alguém sabe algum método no PHP que iguale o valor de uma variável com *string*?

Preciso refatorar o seguinte codigo:

```
 public function hasPlan() : bool
{
    return $this->reference === 'unico' || $this->reference === 'simultaneo';
}
```

Gostaria de alguma dica que retorne booleano e me diga que a variável `$reference` é igual a string 'unico' ou a string 'simultaneo' .

Comment: E qual é o problema com o código atual para que precise refatorá-lo?

Comment: não há problemas, porém acho q possa ser melhorado.

Comment: Se tivesse um método PHP que validasse a string, tipo: 
method_php($reference, ['unico', 'simultaneo'])

Comment: Faz lembrar [Overengineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overengineering) , nem sempre menos código é igual a mais perfomance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo visto, você está considerando que escrever duas vezes a variável é inserir redundância no código. Por um lado é, mas deixa o código mais simples. Se mesmo assim pretende alterar, basta utilizar a função nativa [`in_array`](http://www.php.net/in_array):

```
public function hasPlan() : bool
{
    return in_array($this->reference, ['unico', 'simultaneo']);
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, exatamente isso que procurava, pois se aparecerem mais strings a serem validadas, dessa forma fica mais redundante.

Comment: nossa cara, que função boa, eu não sabia dessa, curti muito.